# Pagination: Reference to page numbered in format of This Page Number/Total Number of Pages

Tags: writing-style

What is the standard way to refer to a page numbered in a format like This Page Number/Total Number of Pages? For example, the top of the page I want to refer to shows “312/1250”

Which of the following would be best:

1. the table on page 312/1250
2. the table on page 312 of 1250
3. the table on page 312

Any reference to an authoritative style guide would also be helpful. I see nothing in the Chicago Manual of Style specifically on this.

Comment: It's on page 312.

Comment: Page referencing, like most referencing questions, are off-topic. This has nothing to do with the English language, it's all about academic writing conventions.

Comment: That said, you should refer directly to the table's own number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're pointing to a specific thing on the page numbered 312, nothing else matters. That is, the total number of pages in the work is irrelevant since you're only talking about one thing on one of the pages.

So the best way to say this is "the table on page 312."